# Adding icon menus to Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, menuitem

I successfully created my first Chrome extension. It now runs only when the extension icon is clicked instead of on the background, and that is great. However, I would like to add more actions to my extension I have been trying to use an extension popup to run other functions but I can't make it work. It doesn't have to be like that, so I am open for suggestions. I do not want to use context menus. I want people to click on the extension icon and show them a "menu".

Right now my extension only alerts a message when it finds a valid page (from mydomain.com), and it finds a hidden field with the name "returnURL". It alerts the value.

I would like to be able to add the ability to click on the icon but instead show an options menu with multiple options.

Something like this:

Click on the extension icon and show two options

- Get Response URL (this option will run the current functionality I have now)
- Do something else (So I could have another function to execute on the
  loaded page)

...and more options if I needed to add them on future versions of my extension.

How do I modify my extension to do that.

Here is my code:

manifest.json

```
    {
            "name": "Get Response URL",
            "version": "1.0",
            "manifest_version": 2,
            "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": "mkto_icon.png",
            "name": "Click to get URL"
            },
            "background":{
                "scripts":["background.js"]
            },
            "permissions":["http://mydomain.com/*"]
     }
```

background.js

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON
        if (tab.url.indexOf("http://mydomain.com/") != -1) { // Inspect whether the place where user clicked matches with our list of URL
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                "file": "contentscript.js"
            }, function () { // Execute your code
                console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
            });
        }
    });
```

contentscript.js

```
    if (document.getElementsByName("returnURL")){
    alert("\nThe Response URL on this form is:\n\n" + document.getElementsByName("returnURL")[0].value);
    }
```

I followed the documentation I found on the Google Extensions developer site but I couldn't make it work. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a real menu with a Chrome extension. You can however show an HTML page when the button is clicked (a pop-up). You can style this HTML page in a way that looks similar to a menu:

```
"browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "mkto_icon.png",
   "default_title": "Click here to open menu",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
```

Add a file `popup.html` to you extension and whatever content you want to show up. Scripts loaded by the pop-up page can load content scripts and communicate with them just like the background page.

For reference: [browser actions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction).

Comment: FYI the reference link is broken now...  this post may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733511/chrome-extension-on-browser-action-create-a-pop-up-and-execute-a-script